# How to get the index of the 5 smallest values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the indexes of the 5 smallest values in an array.

I've tried the code below, however it gives the error: Math.min.apply(...).indexOf is not a function. I'm just not sure what I can use as an alternative?

```
var smallest = [];
for (var i = 0, length = distances.length; i < length; i++) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(null,distances).indexOf();
    if (smallest.length <= 5) {
        smallest.push(min);
    }
    console.log(smallest);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well that expression does not make sense; `Math.min()` returns a single numeric value.

Comment: `Object.entries(distances).sort(([i,a],[j,b]) => a - b).map(([index]) => index).slice(0, 5)`

Comment: What if the same (small) value is in the array twice? Which index do you want?

Answer (score 5):

You could get the keys, sort them with the values and take the top five.

```
var indices = [...distances.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => distances[a] - distances[b])
        .slice(0, 5);
```

Comment: `keys` returns an iterator.

Comment: @charlietfl take a look at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys#Examples)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get `[index, value]` pairs that you can now sort by value to get the order.

```js
const distances = [1, 4, 8, 3, 3, 5, 9, 0, 4, 2];
const indices = Object.entries(distances)
                      .sort(([,a],[,b]) => a - b)
                      .map(([index]) => +index)
                      .slice(0, 5)
console.log(indices);
```

[Nina's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56970645) is better :)

Comment: There's no need to declare `i` or `j` here, you can just write `[,a]` and `[,b]` :)

Comment: @Kobe thx, wasn't sure. And didn't want to use `_` and `__` for these unused arguments

Comment: Yeah, destructuring can get weird sometimes :P

Answer (score 0):

You could add an index to each element, sort the data in ascending order, then splice the first 5 values:

```js
const data = [1, 4, 8, 3, 3, 5, 9, 0, 4, 2]

const indices = data.map((e,i) => [e, i])
  .sort()
  .splice(0,5)
  .map(([,el]) => el)

console.log(indices)
```

Comment: How would this return the indexes?

Comment: Ah, yes, ill fix that now @charlietfl

Comment: @T.J.Crowder haha yes, I always fall victim to not writing in strict mode when writing answers here too.

Comment: `data.slice().map(...)` is pointless. `map` already creates a new Array, you don't need `slice()` anymore. :)